# Problems with combined stream of data by using Binance API

Tags: javascript, websocket, binance, ws, node.js-fs

I am trying to receive combined streamed data of all Binance SPOT Market pairs. I get all token names by calling my development server endpoint with name:

`/exchangeInfo`

I have a problem with my implementation with web-sockets since I can only open 320 web-socket streams, even though Im requesting 377... Could someone help me out?

I researched in the Binance API official docs (https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#websocket-market-streams), but I did not find any limitation for amount of streams combined, so I assume is my implementation error...

Here is my code in the backend:

```
import { busdAllSymbols } from './symbols'

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
//@ts-ignore
// eslint-disable-next-line no-var, @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())

app.get('/exchangeInfo', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const stableCoinName = req.query.stableCoinName as string
    const exchangeInfo = await axios.get(
        'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo'
    )
    const symbols = exchangeInfo.data.symbols.map((el: any) =>
        el.symbol.toLowerCase()
    )
    const symbolsFiltered = symbols.filter((name: string) => {
        return (
            name.substring(name.length - 4) ===
            `${stableCoinName.toLowerCase()}`
        )
    })
    res.send(symbolsFiltered) // all available BSUD pairs in Binance SPOT Market

const server = app.listen(8081, () => {
    console.log('server running')
})

const wss = new WebSocketServer({ server })
const clients = new Set<WebSocket.WebSocket>()

wss.on('connection', (client) => {
    console.log('client is connected')
    clients.add(client) // Actually only 1 client is connected but I made this implementation following chatgpt indications :)

    client.on('message', () => console.log('message received'))

    client.on('close', () => {
        clients.delete(client)
    })
})

const streamBinance = new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws')
streamBinance.on('open', () => {
    console.log('stream opened')
    const subs = {
        method: 'SUBSCRIBE',
        params: busdAllSymbols.map((symbol) => `${symbol}@kline_1m`),
        id: 1,
    }
    streamBinance.send(JSON.stringify(subs))
})

streamBinance.on('message', (message) => {
    clients.forEach((client) => {
        if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
            const contentString = fs.readFileSync(
                `${__dirname}/data.txt`,
                'utf8'
            )
            let contentParsed = JSON.parse(contentString) as any[]
            console.log(contentParsed.length)
            const candle = JSON.parse(message.toString())
            if (contentParsed.length > 0) {
                const isFound = contentParsed.find(
                    (el) => {
                        return el.s === candle.s
                    }
                )
                if (isFound) {
                    contentParsed = contentParsed.filter(
                        (el) => el.s !== candle.s
                    )
                    contentParsed.push(candle)
                } else {
                    contentParsed.push(candle)
                }
            } else {
                contentParsed.push(candle)
            }
            fs.writeFileSync(
                `${__dirname}/data.txt`,
                JSON.stringify(contentParsed.sort((a, b) => a.s - b.s))
            )
        }
    })
})
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I forgot exact details, but you don't need multiple socket connections, nor to fire many requests. You should use single socket connection, then when building socket url, you just add pairs you want to listen to (and you will get candlestick dataset for all define coin pairs). If if find it in docs later, I will post it.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Whirlwind! I will try it this way you suggest :)

Comment: You are welcome! This should be it: https://github.com/binance-us/binance-us-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md ... Look at combined streams and how to build url. Also a related SO link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53999019/3402095

Comment: Yup, I checked in my old code. You use something like : `wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=...` I was getting market pairs from `https//api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo` and with these, I build rest of the stream url

Comment: Example of a stream name to get candlestick data would be : `<symbol>@kline_<interval>` eg. xrpusdt_@1m